# Compare rows based complex conditions in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below.
Which is a data of inspector raising an issue.

```
Iss_id Ins_ID    XY      Duplicate      Raised_Date               Type
1      1        (2,5)    Yes            2019-10-07 10:27:50        A
2      1        (2,5)    Yes            2019-10-07 10:27:50        A
3      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:27:50        A
4      2        (3,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:29:50        A
5      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:29:50        A
6      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:29:50        A
7      3        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 11:27:50        A
8      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 11:27:50        B
9      3        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:27:50        C
10     2        (2,5)    Yes            2019-10-07 10:27:50        A
```

From the above I would like to Find out the Actual duplicate based on conditions

Condition1: Among the Duplicate No, matching all other row. That is, same inspector raising same issue type on same time at same XY.

Expected Output1:

```
Iss_id Ins_ID    XY      Duplicate      Raised_Date               Type
5      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:29:50        A
6      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:29:50        A
```

Condition2: Among duplicate No, same inspector is raising same issue type at same XY within 5 minutes.

Expected Output2:

```
Iss_id Ins_ID    XY      Duplicate      Raised_Date               Type
3      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:27:50        A
5      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:29:50        A
6      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:29:50        A
```

Condition3: Among Duplicate No, At same XY, same issues type within 120 minutes. (Inspector may or may not be same).

Expected Output3:

```
Iss_id Ins_ID    XY      Duplicate      Raised_Date               Type
3      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:27:50        A
5      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:29:50        A
6      2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:29:50        A
7      3        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 11:27:50        A
```

Comment: Timedelta should solve your issue with time difference comparisons

Comment: There is some reason why rows `2  (2,5)  No  2019-10-07    10:29:50    A` are not in Output1? Because it is also duplicates.

Comment: @jezrael can you please specify the issue id?

Comment: @ALI - Only I check duplicatates and get 4 rows 2 times ` 2        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 10:29:50        A` and 2 times `2 (2,5) No 2019-10-07 10:29:50 A`. So ask why second 2 are not duplciates

Comment: @jezrael edited the question can you please check?

Comment: Maybe not understand `Among the Duplicate No, matching all other row. That is, same inspector raising same issue type on same time at same XY.`, can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael for output1: 1. Filter the data where Duplicate == No, then find out the rows which has same Ins_ID and same XY and same Raised_Date and same Type

Comment: yes, but I got 4 rows, not 2 rows if do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205868/discussion-between-ali-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First part answer is matching only dupes `No` columns if not exist `Yes` rows:

```
df['Raised_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Raised_Date'])

df1 = df[df.drop(['Duplicate','Iss_id'], 1).duplicated(keep=False)]
mask = (df1.assign(Duplicate = df1['Duplicate'].eq('No'))
           .groupby(df1.columns.difference(['Duplicate','Iss_id']).tolist())['Duplicate']
           .transform('all'))

df1 = df1[mask]
print (df1)
   Iss_id  Ins_ID     XY Duplicate         Raised_Date Type
4       5       2  (2,5)        No 2019-10-07 10:29:50    A
5       6       2  (2,5)        No 2019-10-07 10:29:50    A
```

For next 2 solution is used [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) function with possible tolerance parameter and checking same columns by parameter `by`:

```
df21 = df[df['Duplicate'].eq('No')].sort_values('Raised_Date').copy()
df22 = df1.drop_duplicates().sort_values('Raised_Date').copy()
#print (df21)
#print (df22)

df2 = (pd.merge_asof(df21, df22, 
                     on='Raised_Date', 
                     by=['Ins_ID','XY','Type'], 
                     tolerance=pd.Timedelta(5 * 60, unit='s'),
                     direction='forward',
                     suffixes=('','_'))
         .dropna(subset=['Duplicate_'])
         .drop(['Duplicate_','Iss_id_'], axis=1))


print (df2)
   Iss_id  Ins_ID     XY Duplicate         Raised_Date Type
0       3       2  (2,5)        No 2019-10-07 10:27:50    A
3       5       2  (2,5)        No 2019-10-07 10:29:50    A
4       6       2  (2,5)        No 2019-10-07 10:29:50    A
```

Similar solution, only need `direction='forward'` and `direction='backward'` (default value, so omited), combine columns and filter non missing rows:

```
df31 = (pd.merge_asof(df21, df22, 
                     on='Raised_Date', 
                     by=['XY','Type'], 
                     tolerance=pd.Timedelta(120 * 60, unit='s'),
                      direction='forward',
                     suffixes=('','_'))
         )
df32 = (pd.merge_asof(df21, df22, 
                     on='Raised_Date', 
                     by=['XY','Type'], 
                     tolerance=pd.Timedelta(120 * 60, unit='s'),
                     suffixes=('','_'))
         )

df3 = df21[df31['Duplicate_'].fillna(df32['Duplicate_']).notna().to_numpy()]
print (df3)
   Iss_id  Ins_ID     XY Duplicate         Raised_Date Type
2       3       2  (2,5)        No 2019-10-07 10:27:50    A
4       5       2  (2,5)        No 2019-10-07 10:29:50    A
5       6       2  (2,5)        No 2019-10-07 10:29:50    A
6       7       3  (2,5)        No 2019-10-07 11:27:50    A
```

Comment: In 3 condition this  7      3        (2,5)    No             2019-10-07 11:27:50        A is missing

Comment: In all cases we have to drop Iss_id first?

Comment: And your requirement is only less values

Comment: within 120 minutes.

Comment: I think higher values. I am confused. 120 min before or 120 min after.

Comment: what to do with Iss_id column (first column)

Comment: @ALI - It is not index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205932/discussion-between-ali-and-jezrael).